# Proof of Rim's Theorem (Milnor)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

I'm currently learning Algebraic K Theory from Milnor's "An Introduction to Algebraic K Theory" and am having trouble understanding his proof of Rim's theorem using a "Mayer-Vietoris" exact sequence. Here is an image of the section:
[image]

By "Hypothesis 1 and 2" Milnor is referring to a Milnor square:

[image]

(Sorry for the poor images). Firstly, I'm unsure how hypothesis $1$ is satisfied. In Charles Wiebel's online source on K-Theory he indicates if you show the kernel of the map $\mathbb{Z}\Pi \to \mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the ideal generated by $\xi -1$ then it is a Milnor square. Why is this true?

Next, in Milnor's proof of Rim's theorem he says "Since $j_{2_*}: K_0\mathbb{Z} \to K_0\mathbb{F}_p$ is clearly an isomorphism it will suffice to verify $j_{1_*} : K_1\mathbb{Z}[\xi] \to K_1\mathbb{F}_p$ is surjective. Why is this enough? I find this rather confusing.

(note: $j_{2_*}$ is the image of $j_2$ under the functor $K_0$ taking rings to abelian groups, $j_{1_*}$ is the image of $j_1$ of $K_1$)

Comment: in your question, $\xi$ is the generator of $\Pi$ of $\xi=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}} $? I suggest see other text , such as "introduction to algebraic k theory" of Silvester in Chapter 7 , or Rosenberg's book of algebraic K-theory and its applications the first three chaptes, because milnor book are more sympathetic to the reader and are not as sophisticated

Comment: the generator is some element $t$. Thanks for the references. I managed to solve the issue on my own...the solution is not as trivial as Milnor's text suggests.